# Bootstrap Modal not working (built in callback not firing)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, jquery-callback

This is driving me insane.

I have 2 modal windows:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="newsletter" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-body span8">
        <h3>Signup for our newsletter<span class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span></h3>
        <label>
            <span>First Name</span>
            <div><input type="text" name="fname"></div>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Last Name</span>
            <div><input type="text" name="lname"></div>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Email Address</span>
            <div><input type="text" name="email"></div>
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
<form action="/search/" method="get" id="search" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-body span12">
        <label>Search: <input type="text" name="q"></label>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And links to trigger each modal:

```
<a href="#newsletter"><i class="icon-newsletter"></i> Get notified</a>
<a href="#search"><i class="icon-search"></i> Search Website</a>
```

With the following relevant styling:

```
.modal-backdrop {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1040;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
    .modal-backdrop.fade {
        opacity:0;
    }
    .modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
        display:block;
        opacity:.9;
        filter:alpha(opacity=90);
    }

.modal {
    position:fixed;
    top:10%;
    left:0;
    z-index:1050;
    width:100%;
}
    .modal.fade {
        -webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
        transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
        top:-100%;
    }
    .modal.fade.in {
        top:10%;
    }
    .modal-body{
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
        background: #FFF;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
        -ms-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
        box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    }
```

And some custom JS for triggering the modals (all # links will either scroll to or otherwise open the target if it's a modal):

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    var top = 0;

    if($(target).hasClass('modal')){
        $(target).modal('toggle');

        if($(window).width() < 960)
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0});
        return;
    }

    if($(target).length > 0){
        top = $(target).offset().top - 65;
    }

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:top},500);
});
```

When clicked, the backdrop shows, but not the modal itself; the built in callback that shows the adds the 'in' class isn't firing. I've debugged it far enough to figure that out, but the fact that this (essentially) exact code works perfectly fine on another site suggest something's iffy with my HTML/CSS/JS. However, I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Ideas?

Comment: Seems to be fine here... http://jsfiddle.net/X5XqG/

Comment: I removed the bootstrap css and it broke again; must be some styling that I missed that it needs. Doing some digging...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I never included the .fade styling; thanks to PSCoder for making that fiddle, which was working due to it including the full bootstrap css.

```
.fade {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
}

.fade.in {
    opacity: 1;
}
```